# 'sudo apt autoremove python3' removed a lot of packages

Tags: apt, package-management, python3

here is a list of packages that were to be removed and I hastily pressed yes and deleted a lot of packages

```
aisleriot apparmor apport apport-gtk aptdaemon apturl apturl-common blender blender-data caribou chrome-gnome-shell
  command-not-found dh-python fastjar firefox flashplugin-installer fonts-dejavu fonts-lato foomatic-db-compressed-ppds gconf2 gdebi
  gdebi-core gdm3 gedit geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gimp-help-common gimp-help-en gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gksu gnome-menus gnome-music gnome-orca
  gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-software gnome-terminal google-chrome-stable
  gsettings-ubuntu-schemas hplip hplip-data ibus ibus-pinyin ibus-table indicator-applet indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime
  indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-session indicator-sound jarwrapper language-selector-common
  libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaio1 libappindicator1 libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libavdevice-ffmpeg56 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
  libboost-locale1.58.0 libboost-regex1.58.0 libboost-thread1.58.0 libcolorpicker-java libevent-core-2.0-5 libfcitx-config4
  libfcitx-gclient0 libfcitx-utils0 libfontchooser-java libgeonames0 libgksu2-0 libglade2-0 libgnome-2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin
  libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common
  libindicator7 libjemalloc1 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libopencolorio1v5 libopenimageio1.6 liborbit-2-0 libpanel-applet0 libpurple-bin
  libruby2.3 libsnapd-glib1 libspnav0 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libtinyxml2.6.2v5 libunity-settings-daemon1
  liburl-dispatcher1 libyaml-cpp0.3v5 lightdm linux-headers-4.10.0-32 linux-headers-4.10.0-32-generic linux-headers-4.10.0-33
  linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-93 linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-96
  linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-4.10.0-32-generic linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-33-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic linux-signed-image-4.10.0-32-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-33-generic lsb-release mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
  mysql-server-core-5.7 nautilus-share openprinting-ppds plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
  printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr
  python-pyatspi python3 python3-apport python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
  python3-brlapi python3-bs4 python3-cairo python3-chardet python3-commandnotfound python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-dbus
  python3-debian python3-defer python3-distupgrade python3-gdbm python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-html5lib python3-louis
  python3-lxml python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-pexpect python3-pil python3-pkg-resources python3-problem-report
  python3-ptyprocess python3-pyatspi python3-pycurl python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-requests
  python3-six python3-software-properties python3-speechd python3-systemd python3-uno python3-update-manager python3-urllib3
  python3-xdg python3-xkit rake rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins ruby
  ruby-did-you-mean ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert ruby-test-unit ruby2.3 rubygems-integration sessioninstaller
  signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 snapd snapd-login-service software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev totem-plugins ubuntu-core-launcher
  ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-standard
  ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-touch-sounds ufw unattended-upgrades unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter
  unity-settings-daemon unoconv update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common usb-creator-common
  usb-creator-gtk vim-gnome vim-gui-common vim-runtime xdiagnose
```

visually speaking everythings looks and works the same, some software like chrome, firefox, gedit, vim, mysql, and even the gnome-terminal were gone but I got those back.

I'm thinking of doing a clean install, but since I don't see much difference then should I just manually reinstall stuff that I use and lost?

How do go about getting these packages back?

running

```
sudo apt install x y z
```

kind of command gives error and I can't install all packages this way like xdiagnos.

I have done a backup of just my data and not the whole system so I can't just go back to a earlier state.

Comment: Now why on earth did you remove `python3`, did you read about its use in Ubuntu???? :-(

Comment: I had built python3 from source and apparenntly I needed a SSL before compiling python so I was going to rebuild it after I intalled SSL.

Comment: Were you aware that `apt ` depends on `python`?

Comment: python 2.7 still existed, and actually for some reason python 3 also still exists. It seems not all packages were removed.

Comment: and no I just came to linux last month, I was not aware apt depends on python.

Comment: What errors do get from `sudo apt install x y z`?

Comment: all those packages depend on python or depend on packages that depend on python, et cetera.

Comment: bash: command not found

Comment: do you get a `bash: command not found` for `sudo apt-get install x y z`? if not you might be able to use it to install the packages maybe. Not sure about that, but removing python is the best possible way to bork your system. A fresh install might be the easier way if you not have loads done on your system yet. If it comes to python you should rely on the provided packages which actually even provide python 3.6 (which still not means you can remove 2.7, 3 or 3.5.